# calling every second a php function and showing a timer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, counter

im trying to work on something when a person clicking start, timer shows and every second I call the php function. I tried some online countup timers but i dont know how to call the function.

```
$("#enter_q").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: '../page.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'enter_q': 'true'},
    success: function(data, status){
        if (data == "ok"){
            $("#timer").innerHTML = '<p>TIMER IS RUNNING</p>';
        }
    }, error: function(xhr, desc, err){
        console.log(xhr);
        conso.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError: " + err);
    }
})

$("#leave_q").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: '../page.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'leave_q': 'true'},
    success: function(data, status){
        if (data == "ok"){
            $("#timer").innerHTML = '<p>TIMER HAS STOPPED</p>';
        }
    }, error: function(xhr, desc, err){
        console.log(xhr);
        conso.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError: " + err);
    }
})
```

this just changes the text from start to the counter in ajax.

Comment: Some code would have been nice...

Comment: What if your request makes more than 1 second to complete???

Comment: what im doing is when the user pess a start button timer starts and every second a php function is giving a number, when the number gets to 10 the  timer stops with a message.

Comment: So in fact you are calling 10x times the PHP function **from** server side???

Comment: basically put the function on page.php and call it in the same page. but as php is a server script there is a chance of it taking longer than 1 second. and you would be putting a lot of stress on the server calling a function every second. why don't you use javascript or jQuery instead. In short this is the wrong way of doing it and client side(jQuery) would be the correct way.

Comment: beacuse the function takes info from a db

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should to use setInterval js-function

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function() { 'make some operatins here' }, 1000)
```

If you want to stop timer just call

```
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Comment: Self calling function using `setTimeout` would be much better ... call it from within completion of each request. Short interval like this using `setInterval` will have lots of request overlaps